# A circular permutation question: selecting a team of knights so that no two knights hostile to each other are selected

Tags: combinatorics

$16$ knights are sitting on a circular table, $7$ knights are required to rescue a girl. Every pair of consecutive knights are hostile to each other. How many number ways when selecting $7$ knights such that no $2$ hostiles can be teamed up? Please guide.

Comment: What have you tried?  Draw a picture, pick one knight to send for now.  How many ways are there to select the other six?

Comment: Sir .i brake the circle into linear form.

Answer (score 0):

If $k$ is the total number of knights in a line and $p$ is the number of knights chosen in a party, there are $p$ selections (Y's) and $k - p$ knights left (N's), with at least one N in between two Y's. Here, $p - 1$ N's are in between the $p$ Y's, because of the 1 N separating two Y's. For this, you can count linear arrangements for $k - 2p + 1$ N's and $p$ selections. There are $\frac{(k-2p+1+p)!}{p!(k-2p+1)!} = \binom{k-p+1}{p}$ methods to do so.

If the selecting knight is part of the team, then $p = 6$ and $k = 13$, as the selected knights cannot be consecutive to the choosing one. Here, $\binom{13-6+1}{6} = 28$.

If the selecting knight is not part of the party, then $p = 7$ and $k = 15$, as there are no restrictions on the knights adjacent to the selecting one. In this scenario, $\binom{15-7+1}{7} = 36$.

These possible scenarios are added to find the total possible combinations.